# Connect Two Computer from Behind Firewalls

Tags: firewall, port, bittorrent, tunnel

The recent advent of BitTorrent Sync has made me curious as to how they accomplish a reliable, peer-to-peer connection between two internet-connected computers.

Within my limited understanding and research, it is my understanding that without an open incoming port on at least one end, that the computers *cannot connect with port tunneling*.  Is this true?  If that's the case, then does that mean that the Sync tracker also behaves as a tunnel?  Would that not mean an exorbitant amount of traffic is hitting their server?

Or is there another way this is accomplished?  I've found this question ([how to ssh two computers behind NAT and Firewall, without third computer](https://superuser.com/q/459202/43554)) which is related, but no completely reliable solution was given without tunneling.

Comment: Both programs have to be enabled in the firewall in order for them to connect to the Internet, AFAIK. If a program is locked, it **cannot** access the Internet, regardless of how the traffic would go from one PC to another.

Comment: In most cases networking equipment can be configured by a program using UPnP. Bittorrent Sync likely does exactly this.  There is a proxy being used in a case like this.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard of course I understand the program must have an outgoing port open, I'm talking about an incoming port.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the lead, I'll look into that.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It would be more helpful to explain why this is a bad question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we're confusing NAT and a Firewall

Lets start with the worst case scenario. You have a properly configured firewall, with *everything* except essential ports locked down both ways. Unless you're using one of those ports (and no one isn't), there's no way you're going to be able to connect two systems on opposite sides of the firewall. This is where tools like [iodine](http://code.kryo.se/iodine/) are useful.

Most home firewalls arn't that restrictive - they disallow many incoming ports but allow most external ports. As such, if the connection is initiated from inside the network, you can connect out to arbitrary resources. Many tunneling methods rely on that - for example your 'classic' reverse ssh implementation.

NAT is not a firewall. *All* it does is let you connect multiple systems, with local ip address ranges, to a single external ip address. Incidentally, this is nearly always paired up with a firewall to let you do things like block and forward ports. In the case of NAT, you may forward ports (or use upnp, even if its out of vogue these days) or use many of the mechanisms that a home firewall would use.

Now that I've gotten all that out of my system, The process we're probably looking at is '[hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching)' and in most cases some flavour of [TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) (since UDP is an option, and I don't see any indication that sync uses another transport mechanism), It also has an option for port mapping via upnp - which from experience is faster. While torrents can tolerate not having ports forwarded, it dosen't work very well that way. Likewise, on a system with the worst case scenario, it wouldn't work at all. Torrents arn't magic.

Chances are *all* the torrent tracker does is (much like a traditional tracker), let you know that the file you want is at a specific client, tell both sides to talk, and then get out of the way.