# How to open a direct ssh between two machines that are connected through a (slow) VPN

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, tunnel

I have two machines that are connected through the same software VPN. The VPN server is far away and slow.

I can open a (slow) ssh link between the machines through the VPN, but I would like to open a direct ssh link between the machines (not through the VPN).

Each machine is behind a NAT on a different public WiFi, so I don't have access to the routers.

Is there any way to use their secure VPN connection, in order to open a direct ssh?

EDIT: I have su permissions on both machines

Comment: To open a direct SSH between the two, outside the VPN, you'll need some control over the routers for such tasks as port forwarding. The VPN has already been configured with the necessary port forwarding as that, too, is a service that needs to be opened between sites/routers to allow the communication between the two VPN servers. You either need to configure the relevant port forwarding or continue using the existing VPN. It seems, with your inability to access the local or remote routers, that your options are limited.

Comment: How do you know that the VPN is slow, and not the connection between the two endpoints?

Comment: @Attie, The VPN is on a different country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to ssh two computers behind NAT and Firewall, without third computer](https://superuser.com/questions/459202/how-to-ssh-two-computers-behind-nat-and-firewall-without-third-computer)